# What is wrong with this question about PowerShell and user impersonation?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

[How to Register-PSRepository for another user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76906179/447901)

This question is four (4) days old with no responses of any kind. Questions in this area are usually responded to quickly, within one (1) day.

Is this a bad question? Have I said something wrong? Is this the impact of the moderator strike?

Please tell me what is wrong with this question.

Comment: I would be surprised if it had to do with the moderator strike specifically. I can't speak to the other questions, as it's well outside of my area of expertise, though perhaps it might be a better fit for [su]?

Comment: (if you want it moved there, just let me know, but it might be better to just repost it yourself so that it shows up as a new question rather than one that's several days old)

Comment: If you needed unconditional affirmation then why ask a question requiring critical analysis (*Is this a bad question? Have I* ...)? You surely understand what downvotes on *Meta* do and don't mean?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I am sure I will be sorry. No, I don't know the meaning. Where can I read documentation on the meaning of downvotes on Meta?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, is this the documentation on Meta downvotes? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/447901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very purpose of PowerShell is *automation*, and its (primary) method is *scripting*, which is a form of *programming*.

While PowerShell is *also* an *interactive shell*, chances are that someone posting on SO is looking for a *scripted* and therefore *programmatic* solution.

However, it never hurts to state that explicitly, i.e. to make clear that you're not just looking for a sequence of manual administration steps to perform interactively, which would indeed be off-topic and should be asked on SU.

The answer to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76906179/447901) is nontrivial, and therefore a *programmatic* solution is unquestionably called for, both for robustness and repeatability.

- I have voted to re-open you question and <del>I encourage others to do the same</del> (*update*: the question has since been reopened); I also encourage you to edit it to make the desire for a programmatic solution obvious.

  - As an aside: It is disheartening to see how many down-votes your question has received. If the argument is simply that it belongs on a *different site*, voting to close accordingly is sufficient; down-voting should be reserved for on-topic, but *poor* questions.

*Update*: The programmatic solution that was previously part of this post has now been posted [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76961462/45375) to your re-opened question.

Comment: Thank you, @mklement0. I have edited the original question to try to convey that this is a scripting/programming effort.

Comment: "If the argument is simply that it belongs on a different site, voting to close accordingly is sufficient; down-voting should be reserved for on-topic, but poor questions." - no, that simply isn't how it works. Questions that are off topic are, inherently, "not useful" to the site, and qualify explicitly for downvoting on that basis. I did not downvote the question, largely because I feel that downvotes beyond -3 serve no purpose whatsoever (they do not meaningfully indicate worsening quality, and -3 is the threshold the enable immediate deletion on closed questions).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: _De facto_ it doesn't work that way - as evidenced by the unnecessary down-votes on the linked question. I'm saying that _it shouldn't work this way_: The dimension of whether a question is _inherently useful_ vs. _whether it  belongs on the site it was posted to_ are unrelated, and punishing askers for - allegedly - picking the wrong site is unnecessary, especially if that assessment turns out to be incorrect (as in the case at hand), in which case the down-votes don't just frustrate the asker, but mistakenly suggest to future readers that the question isn't valid.

Answer (score 10):

### It is entirely off topic

As the tag guidance says, for each tag:

> PowerShell is a cross-platform command line and scripting utility from Microsoft. Use this tag for questions about writing and executing PowerShell scripts ONLY. Programming questions specific to the cross-platform version PowerShell Core (Windows, macOS, and Linux) should be tagged [powershell-core]. Questions about system administration should be asked on Super User or Server Fault.

> Use this tag for questions about writing and executing scripts for PowerShell Core, the cross-platform command line and scripting utility from Microsoft. Questions about Windows PowerShell (the original, Windows-only edition) should be tagged [powershell]. Questions about system administration should be asked on Super User.

The question isn't about writing a script, or doing anything else that's programmatic - it's about a specific system administration task, not any kind of automation. PowerShell is used by many systems administrators, and even home users, who don't go anywhere near programming. As such, the question fails the basic test of [topicality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; **and** is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to** software development

By contrast, here are [recent upvoted questions in the PowerShell tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpowershell%5d%20score%3a1..%20is%3aquestion&searchOn=3). I think the difference is readily apparent between questions that are *actually about programming* vs. ones that are simply about using your computer (admittedly not in a general-audience sort of way - which is why there is a separate Super User site, along with OS-specific Stack Exchange sites).

Comment: Your answer presents a false dichotomy, given PowerShell's core mandate, which is automation. The linked SO question was originally _implicitly_ about scripting, i.e., about a _programmatic_ solution, and now - after an update - _explicitly_ is (sure, it could have done a better job of clarifying its intent originally).
If you were one of the down-voters on the linked SO question, I encourage you to undo your vote: it is a legitimate question calling for a programmatic solution.